# react native states returns undefined inside setinterval function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I don't understand why state returns `undefined` My code is this:

```
class s extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name:null,
          uri:null,
          fbid:null,
        };     
    }

  componentDidMount() {
   setInterval(function(){..
    if(this.state.fbid!=null){..
    ..),1000}
```

this.state.fbid => is undefined

Comment: Have you tried logging `this.state` and using `!==` instead off `!=`? And is it `undefined` in the `didMount` or? Please clarify a little

Comment: ... if(this.state.fbid!=null){ ...runs inside ...setInterval(function(){..

Comment: alert(this.state.uri);
 works but inside setinterval is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is out of context of your function, reason because setInterval function creates their own scope. Try arrow functions instead.

```
componentDidMount() {

    setInterval(() => {
      if(self.state.fbid!=null){
          // do something
      };
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is the best, a.k.a simplest, answer to this problem I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

i guess, in react custom component names should start with capital letter.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kolwq50kj5, working as expected.

Comment: alert(this.state.uri); works but inside setinterval is not working

Comment: i understand now. inside setinterval, there is a function, and "this" refers to context of that function, not your class or component.

Comment: use arrow function, like this: 
setInterval(()=> {
        console.log("this.state.fbid->", this.state.fbid)
      }, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

defining functions will create their own scope here. and `this` bounds to function scope. because `state` is not in function scope you can't access it hence undefined. try using arrow functions instead:

```
componentDidMount() {

  setInterval(() => {
    //do anything
  }, 1000)

}
```